# Why won't my binary tree display?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I don't get it, how come my `display()` method doesn't work?  I could swear that I'm inserting the items correctly into the tree.

Here's my `Node.java` file:

```
public class Node  {
    String data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(Student s) {
        this.data = data;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }
}
```

Here's my `BinaryTree.java` file:

```
    public class BinaryTree {
    private Node root;

    public Node insert(Student s) {
        return insert(this.root, s);
    }

    private Node insert(Node n, Student s) {
        if(this.root == null) { // If the root is null.
            this.root = n;  // Then set root to node n.
            return n; // Return n which is null.
        }
        if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) < 0) { // If the name that's passed in is less than 0.
            if(n.left == null) { // If the left node of the tree is empty.
                n.left = new Node(s); // Then create a left node.
                insert(n.left,s);
            }
            return n.left;
        } else if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) > 0) { // If the name that's passed in is greater than 0.
            if(n.right == null) { // If the right node of the tree is empty.
                n.right = new Node(s); // Then create a right node.
                insert(n.right,s);          
            }
            return n.right;
        }
        return n; 
    }   

    public void display() {
        display(root);
    }

    private void display(Node root)  { 
        if(root == null) { 
            System.out.println("Nothing found.");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            display(root.right);
            System.out.println(root.data);
            display(root.left);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my `Student.java` file:

```
    public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String id;

    public Student(String first, String last, String Identification) {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        id = Identification;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean equals(String studentId) {
        return id.equals(studentId);    
    }

    public int compareTo(String s) {
        int lengthOfLongestString = 0; 
        int i = 0; 
        int a = 0;  
        int b = 0;

        if(lastName.length() < s.length()) { 
            lengthOfLongestString = lastName.length();      
        } else {
            lengthOfLongestString = s.length();  
        }

        if(lastName.charAt(0) == s.charAt(0)) {
            for(i = 0; i < lengthOfLongestString; i++) {
                if(lastName.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i)) {
                    a++;
                    b++;
                    break;
                }
            }       

            if(i == lengthOfLongestString - 1) { 
                return 0;
            }

            if(lastName.charAt(a) < s.charAt(b)) {
                return -1;
            }   
        }
        return 1;
        }
}
```

Here's my `Main.java` file:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("hi", "bye", "brown");
        Student student2 = new Student("hi", "green", "now");

        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        System.out.println(bt.insert(student));
        System.out.println(bt.insert(student2));
        bt.display();
    }
}
```

Here's my `output`:

```
null
null
Nothing found.
```

Comment: How does you node constructor use the Student parameter? It seems like it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: don't swear - debug

Comment: @Lashane I'm completely lost on this.  I've tried debugging for the past 2 hours & still can't find out why this is happening.

Comment: @MikiP It's supposed to insert a student into the node but it's not.

Comment: @yabva89 there are so many mistakes I don't know where to start and I simply cannot do all of it, 1) your node class doesn't use of the argument `Student s`. 2)  this --> `private Node insert(Node n, Student s)` doesn't make sense as a tree should only contain `Node` objects so why do you compare `Node` and a `Student` ? . Basically, the whole tree structure completely confuses me and one incorrect implementation leads to another...

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw I understand, I'll just work off of what you wrote.  Apologies as I'm quite new to Java.

Comment: @yabva89 please have a read at [**this**](http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/binary-search-tree-complete-implementation/). it should give you a basic explanation of the methods used to insert, delete, find nodes within tree etc, and also how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your insert is not properly working for root element and additional insert call after actual insertion. May be the following changes could help.

```
 ...
private Node insert(Node n, Student s) {
    if(this.root == null) { // If the root is null.
        this.root = new Node(s);  // Create a new node and return it
        return this.root; // Return n which is null.
    }
    if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) < 0) { // If the name that's passed in is less than 0.
        if(n.left == null) { // If the left node of the tree is empty.
            n.left = new Node(s); // Then create a left node.
            //insert(n.left,s); // Guess this is not needed as the insert already happened
        }
        return n.left;
    } else if(s.getLastName().compareTo(n.data) > 0) { // If the name that's passed in is greater than 0.
        if(n.right == null) { // If the right node of the tree is empty.
            n.right = new Node(s); // Then create a right node.
            //insert(n.right,s); // Guess this is not needed as the insert already happened          
        }
        return n.right;
    }
  ...
```

Hope it helps!